# Show function inputs and doc string as hint on sublimetext 2 (code hinting?)

Tags: python, function, sublimetext2, hint

Using IDLE, I have appreciated the helpful hint that pops up when you type a function (user or built-in) and open the bracket:

```
    function(
```

so now, in IDLE, the inputs of this function would pop up below, along with a short snippet of doc string. Sublimetext 2 just doesn't do this. Are there any plugins or ways to edit the settings file to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

[SublimeRope](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope) offers code completion, GoTo Definition, etc.

Comment: I've tried that. It always comes up with "warning: evaluating 'function' could not resolve 'function' et..."